# How do I return the cron value with this jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cron

I am new to jQuery how would I get the cron value that is set?
http://jqcron.arnapou.net/demo/#
https://github.com/arnapou/jqcron

```js
  $(function() {
    $('.example1').jqCron();
  });
  $('.example1').jqCron({
    callback: function(value) {
      console.log(value)
    }
  });
```

```html
 <div class="example1"></div>
```

Comment: Documentation is vague. But why use a jQuery plugin for a simple setinterval.

Comment: I wanted the GUI to manage cron jobs by users I have the back end ready just need to get the cron value back

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the method: [`.jqCronGetInstance()`](https://github.com/arnapou/jqcron/blob/master/src/jqCron.js#L227) and store the returned `Object`.
This `Object` will offer useful methods.

```
          var instanceOfCron = $('.example1')
            .jqCron(
              // configuration
              {
                enabled_minute: true,
                multiple_dom: true,
                multiple_month: true,
                multiple_mins: true,
                multiple_dow: true,
                multiple_time_hours: true,
                multiple_time_minutes: true,
                default_period: 'week',
                default_value: '15 10-12 * * 1-5',
                no_reset_button: false,
                lang: 'en'
              }
            )
            .jqCronGetInstance();

          console.log( instanceOfCron.getCron() ) // result: "15 10-12 * * 1-5"
```

[image]

`.jqCronGetInstance()` ussage is visible in the official documentation at example 6: http://arnapou.net/tech-js/jquery-jqcron/